# MYSQL JOINING TWO TABLES Problem which display dublicate id

Tags: mysql

Am trying to learn more on mysql database and I came one problem.
I have two tables

consumables

```
+------------+-----------+-----------------------+------+-------------------+------+
| dod        | item_code | item_description      | dept | quantity_received | unit |
+------------+-----------+-----------------------+------+-------------------+------+
| 2021-12-16 | Jell001   | Petroleum Jelly       | HBT  |                35 | Pcs  |
| 2021-12-16 | ELM001    | Consumer Control Unit | EWM  |                15 | Pcs  |
| 2021-12-17 | ELM002    | D3210 Contactor       | EWM  |                23 | Pcs  |
| 2021-12-17 | ICT001    | Carburator            | ICT  |                23 | Pcs  |
| 2021-12-17 | ICT001    | Carburator            | ICT  |                23 | Pcs  |
| 2021-12-18 | ELM001    | Consumer Control Unit | EWM  |                15 | Pcs  |
+------------+-----------+-----------------------+------+-------------------+------+
```

issue_consumables table

```
+----+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+------+
| id | username | doe        | issued_to    | item_code | quantity_issued | unit |
+----+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+------+
|  1 | STAMP    | 2021-12-18 | John Doe     | ELM001    |               4 | Pcs  |
|  2 | STAMP    | 2021-12-18 | John Doe     | ELM002    |               5 | Pcs  |
|  3 | STAMP    | 2021-12-18 | John Doe     | ICT001    |              35 | Pcs  |
|  4 | STAMP    | 2021-12-15 | Jessy Jesica | Jell001   |              20 | Pcs  |
+----+----------+------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+------+
```

My desired Results

```
+----+-----------+------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| id | item_code | date1      | issued_to    | item_description      | quantity_issued |
+----+-----------+------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
|  4 | Jell001   | 15-12-2021 | Jessy Jesica | Petroleum Jelly       |              20 |
|  3 | ICT001    | 18-12-2021 | John Doe     | Carburator            |              35 |
|  2 | ELM002    | 18-12-2021 | John Doe     | Consumer Control Unit |               5 |
|  1 | ELM001    | 18-12-2021 | John Doe     | Petroleum Jelly       |               4 |
+----+-----------+------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
```

My Query is

```
SELECT
    issue_consumables.id,
    issue_consumables.item_code,
    DATE_FORMAT(issue_consumables.doe,'%d-%m-%Y')as date1,
    issue_consumables.issued_to,
    consumables.item_description,
    issue_consumables.quantity_issued
    FROM consumables
    RIGHT JOIN issue_consumables ON consumables.item_code = issue_consumables.item_code
    ORDER BY issue_consumables.id DESC
```

the Results am getting

```
+----+-----------+------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| id | item_code | date1      | issued_to    | item_description      | quantity_issued |
+----+-----------+------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
|  4 | Jell001   | 15-12-2021 | Jessy Jesica | Petroleum Jelly       |              20 |
|  3 | ICT001    | 18-12-2021 | John Doe     | Carburator            |              35 |
|  3 | ICT001    | 18-12-2021 | John Doe     | Carburator            |              35 |
|  2 | ELM002    | 18-12-2021 | John Doe     | D3210 Contactor       |               5 |
|  1 | ELM001    | 18-12-2021 | John Doe     | Consumer Control Unit |               4 |
|  1 | ELM001    | 18-12-2021 | John Doe     | Consumer Control Unit |               4 |
+----+-----------+------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+
```

where am I doing Wrong to get the desired results

Comment: I think  maybe you should use inner join rather than right join. Duplicates happen because of right join

Comment: INNER JOIN not working

Comment: I can't understand what your desired result is.
does item_code is unique id? if so, than your "consumable" table have a multiple records for a single item.
how do you favor one over another?

Comment: I want a list of issued_consumables problem is am getting dublicate id in the query

Comment: Sure you will have duplicates. `ELM001` it is more than once in  `consumables` table . You should define which unique records you should get from consumables table

Comment: add "GROUP BY "issue_consumables.item_code""
and if you don't want to lose data, add in select part "group_concat(consumables.item_description) as item_description" (actually any grouping function (FIRST/MAX/MIN/GROUP_CONCAT) to each of consumables column)

Comment: Read up on aggregate functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html also RIGHT joins are rarely used an INNER JOIN looks more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a set of `unique item_code` and its description in order to achieve the result.

Something like:

```
select issue_consumables.id,
    issue_consumables.item_code,
    DATE_FORMAT(issue_consumables.doe,'%d-%m-%Y')as date1,
    issue_consumables.issued_to,
    consumables.item_description,
    issue_consumables.quantity_issued
    FROM issue_consumables
join ( select distinct item_code, item_description from consumables ) consumables on consumables.item_code = issue_consumables.item_code
```

to include `quantity_received`

```
select issue_consumables.id,
    issue_consumables.item_code,
    DATE_FORMAT(issue_consumables.doe,'%d-%m-%Y')as date1,
    issue_consumables.issued_to,
    consumables.item_description,
    issue_consumables.quantity_issued,
    consumables.quantity_received
    FROM issue_consumables
join ( select item_code, item_description, sum(quantity_received) quantity_received from consumables group by item_code, item_description ) consumables on consumables.item_code = issue_consumables.item_code
```

Comment: problem is when you insert sum(consumables.quantity_received)as quantity received

Comment: I have added the scenario!! do check

Comment: now working perfectly thanks